# The sum of measures of sets $E_i$ is equal to the sum of $m\,C_m$, where $C_m$ is the set of elements in exactly $m$ of the $E_i$'s.

Tags: measure-theory

I have an measure theory exercise, and I don't figure out any hint for solution:

You have a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$. For each $m\in\{1,2,...,n\}$, define
 $$C_m=\big\{x\,\big |\,x\in E_j \text{ for exactly $m$ indices $j\in \{1,2,...,n\}$}\big\}\,.$$
Show that
$$\sum\limits_{m=1}^n\, \mu(E_m)= \sum\limits_{m=1}^n \,m\,\mu(C_m)\,.$$

I've already seen that those $C_m$'s are the sets which elements in exactly $m$ of the $E_{j}$ sets, but i can't prove the sums are equal. 
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried using induction on $n$?

Answer (score 2):

**Sketch of Proof**

For each $S\subseteq[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, write 
$$A_S:=\big\{x\,\big|\,x\in E_j\text{ for }j\in S\,,\text{ but }x\notin E_j\text{ for }j\in[n]\setminus S\big\}\,.$$
Show that the sets $A_S$'s are measurable and pairwise disjoint.  Also, verify that
$$E_i=\bigcup_{\substack{{S\subseteq[n]}\\{i\in S}}}\,A_S\text{ and }C_m=\bigcup_{\substack{{S\subseteq[n]}\\{|S|=m}}}\,A_S$$
for every $i,m\in [n]$.  Now,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\,\mu\left(E_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\,\sum_{\substack{{S\subseteq[n]}\\{i\in S}}}\,\mu\left(A_S\right)=\sum_{\substack{{S\subseteq[n]}\\{S\neq \emptyset}}}\,|S|\,\mu\left(A_S\right)\,.$$
Thus,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\,\mu\left(E_i\right)=\sum_{m=1}^n\,m\,\sum_{\substack{{S\subseteq[n]}\\{|S|=m}}}\,\mu\left(A_S\right)=\sum_{m=1}^n\,m\,\mu\left(C_m\right)$$