# $\sum_{m=1}^{n}\mu (E_{m})=\sum_{m=1}^{n}m \mu (C_{m})$

Tags: measure-theory

If $(X, S, \mu)$ is a measure space and $E_{1}, ..., E_{n}\in S$.

We define for each $m\in \{1, ..., n\}$ the set $C_{m}=\{x\in X:x\in E_{j}\text{ for exactly }m\text{ indices } j\in\{1, ..., n\}\}$. Show:

i) $C_{m}\in S$

ii) $\sum_{m=1}^{n}\mu (E_{m})=\sum_{m=1}^{n}m \mu (C_{m})$

I solved the first part with induction on n. For the second part I tried to use induction again but I couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Venn diagrams let you see what's happening.  Each $E_j$ is the union of non-overlapping pieces: those elements in $E_j$ alone $(E_{j,1})$, those in $E_j$ and exactly one other $E$, $(E_{j,2})$, those in $E_j$ and exactly two other $E$'s, $(E_{j,3})$, etc.  Since these pieces are non-overlapping, $\mu(E_j)$ is the sum on these pieces.  Alternatively $E_{j,m}=E_j\cap C_m$.

Each $C_m=\cup_{j=1}^nE_{j,m}$. In getting $\sum_{j=1}^n\mu(E_j)$ using $C_m$,  those points in each $C_m$ show up in m terms in the $E_j$ sum as broken down as $E_{j,m}$, so it is necessary to multiply by m when summing $\mu(C_m)$, $\sum_{j=1}^n\mu(E_j)=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{m=1}^n\mu(E_{j,m})=\sum_{m=1}^nm\mu(C_m).$

Comment: I understand your answer but how can you justify the last step?

Comment: Each point in $E_{j,m}$ is repeated in $m-1$ other $E_{I,m}$ so that in $\sum_j\mu(E_j)$ it will turn up in $m$ pieces.  Therefore to equate the measures on both sides you need $m\mu(C_m)$.

Comment: Venn diagram for $n=3$ as example.  There are three pieces where each $E_j$  does not intersect any others.  There are three pieces where exactly two overlap and one piece where all three overlap. When you sum the measures  $\sum_j\mu(E_j)$, those pieces making up $C_1$ appear once, those making up $C_2$ appear twice, while the intersection of three $E_j$ appears three times.

Comment: I struggled with proving this last step today, and also concluded that the best is to put it into words as you have done. Here is a proof that tries to set up a notation, to make it more of a calculation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1911542

Comment: another one is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450282